# Powershell load module in same session

Tags: powershell, import-module, sqlps

I am installing the sqlps module by running PowerShellTools.msi.
After that has been installed I need to use that module in my ps script so I try to do "Import-Module 'sqlps' -DisableNameChecking". But the module is not found. I have to restart powershell to be able to load the module.
Is it possible to load the module in the same session as it was installed?

Comment: It sounds like the app is installing to a path outside of the standard module paths, and updating the PSModule environment variable. 

If this is the case adding this before import should solve the issue : $env:PSModulePath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", "Machine")

Answer (score -1, accepted):

swestner's comment is the solution!